# Real-time data operations in Supabase: Native functionalities or Apollo Client with GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, supabase

I'm building a Next.js application with Supabase as my backend database. I need to perform real-time data operations such as create, update, delete, and show data in real time. I'm exploring two approaches: using the native functionalities of Supabase and using Apollo Client with GraphQL.

I would like to know which approach would be more suitable for my project and what are the trade-offs involved in each. Here's what I've considered so far:

**Native functionalities of Supabase:**

- Supabase Realtime provides real-time event notifications for data
  changes.
- It allows me to subscribe to specific database tables and receive
  real-time updates whenever data is inserted, updated, or deleted.
- It seems like a simpler and more lightweight option, but I'm unsure
  about its capabilities and potential limitations.

**Apollo Client with GraphQL:**

- Apollo Client offers powerful state management and data-fetching
  capabilities.
- GraphQL subscriptions enable real-time updates by subscribing to
  specific data changes.
- It provides features like caching, automatic data synchronization,
  and advanced state management, but it might introduce additional
  complexity.

I want to understand the pros and cons of each approach in terms of performance, scalability, ease of implementation, and maintenance. Additionally, I'd like to know if using Apollo Client and GraphQL subscriptions is necessary if I can achieve real-time functionality with Supabase's native functionalities.

Overall, I want to make an informed decision to ensure efficient and reliable real-time data operations in my Next.js application with Supabase.

Any insights, experiences, or recommendations on the best approach for real-time data operations in Supabase would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!